# Sending JSON data to client django

Tags: python, json, django, swift

I am creating mobile applications for my django web applicaiton. I have it set up like so

**models.py**

```
 class Comment(models.Model):
      CommentDescription = models.CharField(max_length=120)
      Owner = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
      PostToCommentOn = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True)
```

## views.py

```
  def sendJsonDataBackToMobileClient(request,postId):
      comments = Comment.objects.filter(PostToCommentOn = postId)



      jsonString = #create an organized json string from comment models

      return HttpResponse(jsonString)
```

I'm not sure how to organize a json of my comment models to make a lightweight response to my mobile application client in swift

Answer (score 3):

Take a look over [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
>>> from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> response.content
b'{"foo": "bar"}'
```